# How to print line by line of read c file after removing comments from it using perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
use Regexp::Common qw( comment );
local $/ = undef;
$_ = <DATA>;
s/$RE{comment}{C}//gs;
```

I have read complete file data and removed all comments from the read file. 
Now I want to  print line by line instead of printing all data at once.

as per my understanding complete file data is in string `$_`. 
How to convert it into a array so that I can print it line by line.

If the file data is in array I can do some string matching like that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my @filecontents = split /\n/; # assuming the data is in $_
print "$_\n" foreach (@filecontents);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string at newline, and output the result list one by one.

```
foreach my $line (split /\n/) {
    print "$line\n";
}
```

Or

```
say for (split /\n/);
```

If your Perl supports `say`.